# How to Use bpy.ops.object.add_named()?

Tags: python

Is this a bug or is there a preliminary step I need to take to make the object operators available?

````
>>> bpy.ops.object.add_named(linked=True, name="Bob")
Error: Object not found

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Object not found
```
````

Comment: Never used this operator. Is an alternative for duplicate. Requires "Bob" to be in the scene, otherwise throws error object  "Bob" is not found.  Not a bug.

Comment: Thanks, @batFINGER. I was actually trying to solve a different problem when I came across that. I'll regroup and if I have no luck following other avenues, I'll post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
bpy.ops.object.add_named(linked = True, name = "Cube.010")
```

I get it now. The name of this function, `add_named()` is misleading. It's not about adding a new object and naming it as it's created. It's about copying an existing, named, object.

What I was originally looking for was a way to link a `copy()`ed object to the original so they share data. The idea was to use `copy()` to make the new object, then it could be either:

- linked into a collection as an independent object, or
- linked to another object so they share data.

It seemed like a logical assumption to make that a `copy()`ed object might have these options open.

Still exploring...

Comment: Why not use `bpy.ops.object.duplicate()` ? It has a `linked` property

Comment: @Gorgious: Because at this point, I'm not trying to solve a specific problem, I'm exploring the possibilities of Blender Python.

Comment: Alright then, seems you figured it out :) You can mark your answer as accepted so that others may stumble upon it if they dig in the same place. Cheers

Comment: Can't do that until tomorrow.